Constant Current Thermal Inconsistencies LED Circuit LM317


Hello,
I'm using this circuit below to drive some LEDs. I have 500 hundred of them and I have about 10% of them that behave in an inconsistent way. 90% operate with a constant current output from the LM317 output of 0.75A (This slowly linearly reduces to zero A at about 150C case temp of the LM317.).
The 10% of them however abruptly go from 0.75A on he output of the LM317 to 0A at 50C case temp of the LM317.
I have tried doing a simple A/B test to see if it's related to the LM317 specifically. I swapped a LM317 from the 90% "working" batch into the 10% "non-working" non-working batch. This seemed to have resolved the issue with a 50% success rate.
I did the same A/B swap with the Mosfet's on the ground side of the LEDs and had a similar 50% success rate. I'm having a hard time finding a 100% commonality of a singular part that is the root cause of this erratic thermal behaviour.
I've also localized heat with a hot air gun on the PCB around the LM317 or the MOSFETs. It seems heating up the LM317 or the MOSFETs will cause this shutoff on almost all of the 10% lower temp parts.
I'm a little stumped on why this would be happening. Any ideas of measurements, troubleshooting, or things to look further into would be greatly appreciated.
Also, not I've checked loose connections, reflowed the solder on many of the 10% of PCBS, checked for cold solder joints and that does not seem to be the issue.

You have LED strings in parallel with no balancing resistors, which is a recipe for unbalanced current. What do you mean by "The 10% of them however abruptly go from 0.75A on he output of the LM317 to 0A at 50C case temp of the LM317."

500 or 50000?   ...

Even without this issue, your circuit is a recipe for problems, unless you carefully ensure that you always turn on the same number of LED strings.

I mean,  you even notice that the circuit is non-viable, as you notice that LM317s get too hot. Time for a switch-mode constant current supply architecture, I'd say, or at least for way more distributed linear current regulation.

Luckily, multi-channel switch-mode digitally controlled LED string supplies are a commercial thing that you can buy for much less than it costs to actually build a board with 500 (or 50000?) of your LM317, if you factor in the cost of your external resistors, the cost of the extra low-side n-channel MOSFETs and their gate resistors and board and construction costs, not to mention that burning energy in linear regulators is just wasting power AND makes thermal design harder. I'd probably just convert your "double LED strings" of 2×3 LEDs (which are a bad idea!) into actual purely serial string

… of 6 LEDs, and use something like a single TPS92360 per such string. Has a "control" input with which you can turn the string on and off, eradicates all the LM317s, all the MOSFETs, solves your design mistake of putting LED strings in parallel with no balancing, could easily be controlled en masse with I²C I/O expanders, or simple shift registers at logic levels, thus simplifies wiring dramatically… (If you really need to work from a high voltage down, there's equivalent buck instead of boost current regulators, e.g. LM3406)

Thank you for the responses. We used to use a switch mode buck supply. I believe it was a LT part and we ran into sourcability of parts at higher volumes. So we switched to the LM317 because it was such a common part with multiple alternates available. The loss of power as heat isn't as important  from a thermal management perspective in the appication as these circuits sit around 60C-70C during normal operation steady state. From extra power I am ok with the in efficiencyof the circuit and prefer a part with more alternates and low cost. The balancing resistor make sense.

I am wondering why 90%(450 PCBs) of the PCVs with this circuit operate up to 150C, but the other 10%(50 PCBs) are turning off at 50C. I should mention yes only one string of 3P2S LEDs are on at one time. The Channels for each MOSFET is turned on at the gate by a micro controller at 3.3V. Until recently I noticed this issue with varying behavior of some PCBs at varying temperatures. I have been using this circuit for some time at fairly large volumes(200k) a year with seemingly no issues from the variance in forward voltage of the LEDs. Agreed the balancing resistors would be best practice.

With each LED having a slightly different forward voltage \$V_F\$, connecting them all in parallel like this is definitely asking for trouble. Some chains will draw very different current than the others. The fact that you are using a current source to power them exacerbates the problem.
You can kill two birds with one stone, though. A resistor will provide some elasticity to the combined \$V_F\$ of each set of three series-connected LEDs, helping to balance current in each chain. Additionally, potential difference developed across these resistors as they balance current is voltage that is no longer across the regulator, reducing regulator power dissipation:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Estimating 350mA through R1 and R2, each resistor is dissipating power:
$$ P_{R1} = I^2R_1 = 2.7W $$
While that sounds like a lot, it's power that's not being dissipated in the regulator. The 7V or so developed by R1 and R2 (and all the others) is 7V less for the regulator to dispense with. In the above examples, regulator power dissipation has gone from \$750mA \times 10.9V=8.2W\$ down to \$750mA \times 3.4V=2.6W\$.
You'll have to size your resistors appropriately, for the supply you have, regulator drop-out, and the balancing you find acceptable. For instance, the LM317 has terrible drop-out voltage, requiring 3V or so of "overhead". Using a 24V supply, that leaves you with 21V.
Take off some room for the regulator to maneuver, say 2V, and you have only 19V.
The current sense resistor array has a further 1.25V across it, leaving us with a little under 18V for the LEDs and resistors.
If each LED in a chain of three develops \$V_F=3V\$ with 350mA through it, then each chain develops \$3\times V_F=9V\$ total, and the maximum voltage remaining for the resistors is 9V. Some chains are worse than others, so for some leeway let's try to get 7V across the resistors on average:
$$ R = \frac{V}{I} = \frac{7V}{350mA} = 20\Omega $$
It seems likely to me that you have forgotten to account for various "losses" of voltage, such as regulator drop-out, 1.25V across the sense resistance, and some across the MOSFETs. They add up, and if they all leave you with less than the required \$3\times V_F\$ across the LED chains, then things won't work as you expect.

Thanks for these calculations. This makes sense with the trade off of power dissipation in the balancing resistors instead of in the LM317. I'm wondering if without these balancing resistors why I would be seeing some units turn off at a lower temp 50C and others turn off at a higher temp 150C. I will definitely double check the operating conditions of the LM317 are all being satisfied (Drop Out voltage, power dissipation for the package, etc.). Also yes the RDSon of the FETs causes some voltage drop along with the LEDs. I've measure the output of the LM317 and it typically will real ~9.3V .

The input voltage at the power supply going into the LM317 is 15V so the dropout voltage I believe is satisfied. I'm just wondering if there is something that could be causing either the LM317 or the MOSFET to turn off that is a function of temperature that I would be missing that's causing these units to turn off abruptly.

I guess a good exercise for me to try would be cut a trace with the 2 strings of 3 LEDs and measure the forward voltage of the LEDs independently. I suspect maybe as the LEDs are heating up the forward voltage drops, but the variance of this forward voltage depending on the LEDs maybe be causing all of the current to primarily go through one 3 Series set of LEDs.

Some LM317 users report that thermal shutdown occurs at 150C, which definitely should not occur at 125C or under, but there will also be hysteresis, preventing the regulator from turning back on before temperature has dropped significantly lower than 125C. With a constant voltage supply, LEDs will take whatever current they take, but with a constant current source behaviour will be very different. It's possible that the lowest $V_F$ chains will almost completely starve the others of current, which may explain some off/others on, and the sharp transitions leading up to that.
